# Assignment Cache Simulator in C

Tags: c

I have an assignment for the Cache Simulator. every time I run code it gives error1 that is used in the if statement. I am trying to open the input file but it didn't open and gives error1. I tried to catch this error but failed.
I am posting my whole code because I don't want to make assumptions about where the problem may lie. Can anyone tell where I am making a mistake?
Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

struct cacheBlock{
    unsigned int valid;
    unsigned long int tag;
    unsigned int time;
    struct cacheBlock *next;
};

int memoryReadsNoPrefetch = 0;
int memoryWritesNoPrefetch = 0;
int cacheHitsNoPrefetch = 0;
int cacheMissesNoPrefetch = 0;
int memoryReadsPrefetch = 0;
//int memoryWritesPrefetch = 0;
int cacheHitsPrefetch = 0;
int cacheMissesPrefetch = 0;

int powerOfTwo(int num){
    if(num==0){
        return 0;
    }
    while(num!=1){
        if(num%2!=0){
            return 0;
        }
        num=num/2;
    }
    return 1;
}

struct cacheBlock** allocateCache(int sets, int n){
//printf("Aa\n");
    struct cacheBlock** temp = malloc(sizeof(struct cacheBlock) * sets);
//printf("Ab\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sets; i++){
//printf("Ac\n");
        temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct cacheBlock) * n);
//printf("Ad\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
//printf("Ae\n");
                temp[i][j].valid=0;
//printf("Af\n");
            }
//printf("Ag\n");
    }
//printf("Ah\n");
    return temp;
}

void readNoPrefetch(struct cacheBlock** cache, unsigned long tag, int index, int sets, int n){
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        if(cache[index][i].valid==1 && cache[index][i].tag==tag){
            flag=1;
            cacheHitsNoPrefetch++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1){
        return;
    }else{
        cacheMissesNoPrefetch++;
        memoryReadsNoPrefetch++;
        int full = 1;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                    if(cache[index][i].valid==1){
                            cache[index][i].time++;
                    }
                    if(cache[index][i].valid==0){
                            full = 0;
                            break;
                    }
            }
            int max=0;
            if(full == 1){
                    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                            if(cache[index][i].time > max){
                                    max = cache[index][i].time;
                            }
                    }
                    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                            if(cache[index][j].time==max){
                                    cache[index][j].valid=0;
                                    cache[index][j].tag=(-1);
                                    cache[index][j].time=0;
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
            if(cache[index][i].valid==0){
                cache[index][i].valid=1;
                cache[index][i].tag=tag;
            }
        }
    }
}           

void writeNoPrefetch(struct cacheBlock** cache, unsigned long tag, int index, int sets, int n){
        int flag = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(cache[index][i].valid==1 && cache[index][i].tag == tag){
            flag = 1;
            cacheHitsNoPrefetch++;
                        memoryWritesNoPrefetch++;
            break;
                }
        }
        if(flag==1){
                return;
        }else{
            readNoPrefetch(cache, tag, index, sets, n);
        memoryWritesNoPrefetch++;
                return;
        }
}

void prefetch(struct cacheBlock** cache, unsigned long int address, int prefetch_size, int n, int blockSize, int setBits, int offsetBits){
        int flag=0;
        unsigned long int prefetch_address = address;
        for (int i = 0; i < prefetch_size; i++){
                prefetch_address = prefetch_address + blockSize;
                int Mask = (1 << setBits) - 1;
                unsigned int set_index = (prefetch_address >> offsetBits) & Mask;
                unsigned long tag = (prefetch_address >> offsetBits) >> setBits;
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                        if(cache[set_index][j].valid==1 && cache[set_index][j].tag==tag){
                            flag=1;
                            break;
            }
                }
                if(flag==1){
                        return;
                }else{
            memoryReadsPrefetch++;
                    int full = 1;
                    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                            if(cache[set_index][i].valid==1){
                                        cache[set_index][i].time++;
                            }
                            if(cache[set_index][i].valid==0){
                                        full = 0;
                                        break;
                            }
                    }
                    int max=0;
                    if(full == 1){
                            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                                    if(cache[set_index][i].time > max){
                        max = cache[set_index][i].time;
                                    }
                            }
                            for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                                    if(cache[set_index][j].time==max){
                                            cache[set_index][j].valid=0;
                                            cache[set_index][j].tag=(-1);
                                            cache[set_index][j].time=0;
                                            break;
                                    }
                            }   
                    }
                    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
                            if(cache[set_index][i].valid==0){
                                    cache[set_index][i].valid=1;
                                    cache[set_index][i].tag=tag;
        //                          memoryReadsPrefetch++;
                            }
                    }
        }
        }
}


void readPrefetch(struct cacheBlock** cache, unsigned long tag, int index, int sets, int n, int prefetch_size, int blockSize, int offsetBits, int setBits, unsigned long int address){
        int flag=0;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
                if(cache[index][i].valid==1 && cache[index][i].tag==tag){
                        flag=1;
                       cacheHitsPrefetch++;
                        break;
                }
        }
        if(flag==1){
        //cacheHitsPrefetch++;
                return;
        }else{
        cacheMissesPrefetch++;
        memoryReadsPrefetch++;
              int full = 1;
              for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                        if(cache[index][i].valid==1){
                                cache[index][i].time++;
                        }
                        if(cache[index][i].valid==0){
                                full = 0;
                                break;
                        }
                }
                int max=0;
                if(full == 1){
                        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                                if(cache[index][i].time > max){
                                        max = cache[index][i].time;
                                }
                        }
                        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
                                if(cache[index][j].time==max){
                        cache[index][j].valid=0;
                                        cache[index][j].tag=(-1);
                                        cache[index][j].time=0;
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                }
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
                        if(cache[index][i].valid==0){
                                cache[index][i].valid=1;
                                cache[index][i].tag=tag;
                        }
                }
        prefetch(cache, address, prefetch_size, n, blockSize, setBits, offsetBits);
    }
}

void writePrefetch(struct cacheBlock** cache, unsigned long tag, int index, int sets, int n, int prefetch_size, int blockSize, int offsetBits, int setBits, unsigned long int address){
        int flag = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                if(cache[index][i].valid==1 && cache[index][i].tag == tag){
                        flag = 1;
            cacheHitsPrefetch++;
                        break;
                }
        }
        if(flag==1){
        //cacheHitsPrefetch++;
                return;
        }else{
        readPrefetch(cache, tag, index, sets, n, prefetch_size, blockSize, offsetBits, setBits, address);
        return;
        }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
//error checks
        if (argc != 7){
                printf("error1\n");
                exit(0);
        }
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[6], "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
            printf("error2\n");
            exit(0);
    }
    int cacheSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    int blockSize = atoi(argv[2]);
    int prefetchSize = atoi(argv[5]);
    int n = 0;
    int setNumber = 0;
    if(powerOfTwo(cacheSize)==0 || powerOfTwo(blockSize==0)){
                printf("error3\n");
                return 0;
        }

    /*if(strcmp(argv[4], "fifo")!=0 || strcmp(argv[4], "lru")!=0){
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }else if(strcmp(argv[4], "lru")==0){
        return 0;
    }*/

    if(strcmp(argv[4], "direct")==0){
        n = 1;
        setNumber = cacheSize/blockSize;
    }else if(strcmp(argv[4], "assoc")==0){
        n = cacheSize/blockSize;
        setNumber = 1;
    }else if(strncmp(argv[4], "assoc:", 6)==0){
        sscanf(argv[4], "assoc:%d", &n);
        if(powerOfTwo(n)==0){
            printf("error5\n");
            return 0;
        }
        setNumber = cacheSize/(blockSize*n);
    }else{
        printf("error4\n");
        return 0;
    }
//all inputs are valid
    struct cacheBlock** noPrefetchCache = allocateCache(setNumber, n);
    struct cacheBlock** prefetchCache = allocateCache(setNumber, n);
    int offsetBits = (int) (log(blockSize)/log(2));
    int setBits = (int) (log(setNumber)/log(2));
    unsigned long int address = 0;
    char readOrWrite = ' ';
    int Mask = (1 << setBits) - 1;
    while((fscanf(fp, "%c %lx\n", &readOrWrite, &address)!=EOF && readOrWrite!='#')){
        unsigned int set_index = (address >> offsetBits) & Mask;
        unsigned long tag = (address >> offsetBits) >> setBits;
        if(readOrWrite=='R'){
            readNoPrefetch(noPrefetchCache, tag, set_index, setNumber, n);
            readPrefetch(prefetchCache, tag, set_index, setNumber, n, prefetchSize, blockSize, offsetBits, setBits, address);
        }else if(readOrWrite=='W'){
            writeNoPrefetch(noPrefetchCache, tag, set_index, setNumber, n); 
            writePrefetch(prefetchCache, tag, set_index, setNumber, n, prefetchSize, blockSize, offsetBits, setBits, address); 
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("no-prefetch\n");
    printf("Memory reads: %d\n", memoryReadsNoPrefetch);
    printf("Memory writes: %d\n", memoryWritesNoPrefetch);
    printf("Cache hits: %d\n", cacheHitsNoPrefetch);
    printf("Cache misses: %d\n",  cacheMissesNoPrefetch);
    printf("with-prefetch\n");
    printf("Memory reads: %d\n", memoryReadsPrefetch);
    printf("Memory writes: %d\n", memoryWritesNoPrefetch);
    printf("Cache hits: %d\n", cacheHitsPrefetch);
    printf("Cache misses: %d\n",  cacheMissesPrefetch);
}
```

Comment: Post a [mre]. Don't expect other people to do that work for you.

Comment: Also post how you call this program, and provide sample input. Because the only way I see how `error1` would normally be the output, is when you don't pass exactly 6 arguments on the command line.

Comment: Have you considered writing a tiny program that prints out the value of `argc`, and running it with various arguments to see what the behavior is?  Useful reading can be found here: [main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)